# How do I declare one-to-one relation in code-first ef.1

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I have two classes

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Avatar Avatar { get; set; }

    }

public class Avatar
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LinkInString { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Uri Link
        {
            get { return new Uri(LinkInString); }
            set { LinkInString = value.AbsoluteUri; }
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

`User` has one `Avatar` or zero.

When I add 2 Users

```
db.Users.Add(new User() { Avatar = new Avatar() { Link = new Uri("http://myUrl/%2E%2E/%2E%2A") }});
db.Users.Add(new User() { Avatar = new Avatar() { Link = new Uri("http://myUrl/%2E%2E/%2E%2B") }});
db.SaveChanges();
```

every `Avatar` has 0 as `UserId`, and of course Users has 1 and 2 as its `Id.`

How can I  fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework does not support one-to-one relationships unless it is a shared primary key mapping. So in your case you can not have a navigational property `Avatar` in the `User` class. Instead you can have `User` property in `Avatar` class.

```
public class User
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }


}

public class Avatar
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LinkInString { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Uri Link
        {
            get { return new Uri(LinkInString); }
            set { LinkInString = value.AbsoluteUri; }
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can add entities as follows

```
var user = new User();
var avatar = = new Avatar() { User = user, Link = new Uri("http://myUrl/%2E%2E/%2E%2A") };
db.Users.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You are almost right. I can have a navigational property Avatar in the User class, but only then I haven't a navigational property User in the Avatar class. So there are 2 options. Actually there is a 3rd option - User and Avatar could exists in the same table and we could add a property Id in the Avatar class and add HasRequired(a => a.Avatar).WithRequiredPrincipal(); in the UserConfiguration, and HasKey(a => a.Id); in the AvatarConfiguration.